# Unexpected Django Error [Django 1.5.1]

Tags: python, django

I am just trying to Migrate on of my Django project from version 1.4.22 to 1.5.1.

Actually I am working on a package which is actually built in Django 1.4.10 and client needs to get it migrated to the latest version.
It works fine upto 1.4.22 but not for 1.5.1

here is the package info: https://github.com/prikhi/AcornAccounting

It all goes well, but when I tried to run the server it started throwing the following error:

> from django.http import HttpResponseRedirectBase, HttpResponse
>   ImportError: cannot import name HttpResponseRedirectBase

But the thing is this line is not being used anywhere in my code.

**Note: I am running the project on a virtual environment.**

and here is the complete error message:

> from django_ajax.encoder import serialize_to_json
>      File
>   "/home/dev31/.virtualenvs/AcornAccounting/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_ajax/encoder.py",
>   line 8, in
>
> ```
> from django.http import HttpResponseRedirectBase, HttpResponse
> ```
>
> ImportError: cannot import name HttpResponseRedirectBase

I tried to resolve this error but nothing helped. Please help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you using django ajax ?

Comment: why are you using such an old version of django?

Comment: @AR7 Thanks for the quick response, actually I am working on a package which is actually built in Django 1.4.10 and client needs to get it migrated to the latest version.
here is the package info: https://github.com/prikhi/AcornAccounting

Comment: but isn't the latest version 2.0?

Comment: @AR7 yes it is, but I am trying to proceed step by step.

Comment: It seems like the version of django-ajax you are using is not compatible with that version of Django itself.